# Can't get JavaScript Array to work in OOP style

Tags: javascript, arrays, oop

Hi currently I'm trying to get following snippet of code to work:

```
function Entry() {
    var pauses = new Array();
}

Entry.prototype = {
   AddElement: function(aParameter) {
      this.pauses.push(aParameter);
   }
}
```

Unfortunately this code fails with following error in Safari if I try to call AddElement("Test");

TypeError: Result of expression 'this.pauses' [undefined] is not an object. Does anybody know why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, `pauses` is a local variable within the `Entry()` function, not a member on the object constructed by it.

You want to replace `var pauses = ...` with `this.pauses = ...`.

Answer (score 1):

change

```
var pauses = new Array();
```

to

```
this.pauses = new Array();
```

or, better

```
this.pauses = [];
```

Comment: whats the difference between new Array() and []?